# AutofacRegistrationExtensions.ConfigureConsumers(IComponentContext) Register Receive Endpoints by Convention

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to register Receive Endpoints by convention *(in MT v6.0)* but when doing so their Consume() method is never invoked. If I register manually by setting up ReceiveEndpoint() then it works, but ideally I'd be able to do this by convention since the Bus wire-up occurs in a base class and auto-discovery is nice.

It's unclear what the naming convention is that ConfigureEndpoints(IComponentContext) relies on, and I'm not sure if the default behavior applies to the queue name itself or the name of the consumer class. A couple of thoughts there:

1. If the default convention applies to consumer class name that doesn't seem to make sense because the classes could be identified by their implementation of `IConsumer<T>` where T is the queue message. By default the behavior should be to discover and wire-up anything implementing `IConsumer<T>`.
2. If the convention applies to the queue name, meaning the queue name must match T that makes more sense but in my case my queue and T are both "IFileReceived" and there's a message in the queue but Consume() still is not invoked.. so maybe the convention relies on a fully namespaced T, i.e. MyNamespace.IFileReceived for the queue name? If that's the case then there's the problem.

My consumer class is definitely registered in the Autofac container, I can see it in the Registrations collection, so it seems my problem is due to naming conventions or something else. Any ideas? I couldn't find anything online in regards to registering receive endpoints by convention unfortunately.

```
new ContainerBuilder().AddMassTransit(x => 
{
    x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());

    x.AddBus(bus => MassTransit.Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
    {
        config.Host(new Uri(serviceBusHost), h =>
        {
            h.Username(serviceBusUsername);
            h.Password(serviceBusPassword);
        });

        config.ConfigureEndpoints(bus);

    }));
});
```

Comment: 2. Yes, fully namespaced type names are used for message types. As you stated, I would agree, that may be your problem if your message producer isn't using the same namespace for the message contract.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I’ll have a look. But now that I think about it, assuming the fully namespaced contract was being used via the auto-registration of my consumer, I would have seen a queue in RabbitMQ with the namespace as part of it. The only queue is the original “IFileReceived” sans a namespace. Both the producer and the consumer use the same interface. So that makes me think something else is going on, but I’ll have a look. Thanks

Comment: Default endpoint names are based upon the consumer: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Configuration/Definition/DefaultEndpointNameFormatter.cs#L85 -- there are also SnakeCase and KebabCase formatters.

Comment: Thanks. I dug in a bit more, hopefully this clarifies the issue. If I explicitly use config.ReceiveEndpoint(queueName, configureEndpointDelegate) then the queue and exchanges are created in RabbitMQ and everything works. However, if I rely on config.ConfigureEndpoints(bus) no exchanges nor queue are created so that leads me to believe it's not discovering the consumer class that implements IConsumer<IFileReceived>. If I probe bus.Registrations I do see the class, but ConfigureEndpoints() isn't finding it.

Comment: If you can narrow it down to a simple reproducible case, submit it as an issue and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the help. I've figured it out. My call to x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()); was using Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() which appeared correct however it wasn't my endpoint that contained the subscriber, it was actually MassTransit.AutofacIntegration. The fact that my overall Autofac container did in fact contain my subscriber confused the issue. At the end of the day the assembly passed to AddConsumers() must contain the subscriber else it's not available when ConfigureEndpoints() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to:

`x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());`

I expected my consumer to be in the assembly returned by GetCallingAssembly() when in fact the assembly was MassTransit.AutofacIntegration. Changing the line to the following fixed the issue:

`x.AddConsumers(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());`

The confusing part was that IComponentContext passed into the following did in fact contain my subscriber but that alone isn't good enough. Consumers must be discovered by the AddConsumers() call:

`config.ConfigureEndpoints(bus);`

The bus variable contains my subscriber from an Autofac/DI standpoint, but not from a MassTransit standpoint.